# Even after enabling spark.ui.enabled to false in spark defaults is not disabling access in Spark 2.1.0

Tags: apache-spark

Even after enabling spark.ui.enabled to false in spark defaults ( verified it is available in node ) and still UI is accesible. Any clues? I am looking to disable the UI